# UIView added with incorrect orientation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

So I have been working on a problem with UIView on the iPad.  Essentially I have a splitview as the root view and I want to overlay my custom image view over top of the splitview (This is because the splitview must be the root view).  The problem that I have, is when I call addSubview on my splitview the subview gets displayed in its default orientation, with no regard to the iPad's current orientation. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or flag I am not setting?

Thanks!

Code that I am using to add the view:

```
[splitViewController.view addSubview: myImageController.view];
```

Example screenshots: http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~krtaylor/so/

Comment: possible related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024138/adding-uiviewcontroller-view-to-another-view-causes-orientation-problems/3059100#3059100

Answer (score 1):

So if figured out a solution and that is to programmatically create the view and use UIDevice's currentOrientation to size the view properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, seams resolved by removing from the parent view the "autoresize subview" option in IB.
Select the view a then: Inspector -> Attributes (first tab) -> drawing.