# Adding UIViewController.view to another view causes orientation problems

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, orientation

**Short version:**
I'm alloc/init/retaining a new UIViewController in one UIViewControllers viewDidLoad method, adding the new View to self.view. This usually works, but it seems to mess up orientation change handling of my iPad app.

**Longer version**:
I'm building a fairly complex iPad application, involving a lot of views and viewcontrollers. After running into some difficulties adjusting to the device orientation, I made a simple XCode project to figure out what the problem is.

Firstly, I have read the Apple Docs on this subject (a small document called  ["Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1688.html)), and while I do believe it has something to do with one of the reasons listed there, I'm not really sure how to fix it.

In my test project I have an appDelegate, a rootViewController, and a UISplitViewController with two custom viewControllers. I use a button on the rootViewController to switch to the splitViewController, and from there I can use a button to switch back to the rootViewController. So far everything is great, i.e. all views adjust to the device orientation.

However, in the right viewController of the splitViewController, I use the viewDidLoad method to initialize some other viewControllers, and add their views to its own view:

self.newViewController = [[UIViewController new] autorelease];
 [newViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];

This is where things go wrong. Somehow, after adding this view, adjusting to device orientation is messy. On startup everything is fine, after I switch to the splitViewController everything is still fine, but as soon as I switch back to the rootViewController it's all over. I have tried (almost) everything regarding retaining and releasing the viewcontroller, but nothing seems to fix it.

As you can see from the code above, I have declared the newViewController as a property, but the same happens if I don't.

Shouldn't I be adding a ViewController's view to my own view at all? That would really mess up my project, as I have a lot of viewControllers doing all sorts of things.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I have the same problem, actually my application can work only in landscape mode and have 3 views, all configured as landscape in IB.
The first one, loaded automatically is loaded in the right orientation but if i try to add a subview the new view is in portrait mode. Still digging.

Comment: possible related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656088/uiview-added-with-incorrect-orientation/3059099#3059099

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, seams resolved by removing from the parent view the "autoresize subview" option in IB.
Select the view a then: Inspector -> Attributes (first tab) -> drawing.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that your new viewcontroller is getting the autorotation calls and probably not handling them.  Meanwhile your old viewcontrollers and its views won't get the autorotation calls and will be stuck in whatever orientation they were in.

I can't tell, but I think what you want to do is to make a UIView and add it to your old viewcontroller, instead of making a UIVIewController and adding its view.